# Closing an FPDF table and returning to full line format

Tags: php, fpdf

I have created a table using fpdf, and I'm populating it using the `MultiCell` call.  But I'd like to close the table and add some full length text after it. I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set x to 0 by using SetX(0) and then use multicell with full width text.
Ex:-

```
$pdf->SetX(0)
$pdf->MultiCell(200,10,'Testing',0,'L')
```

Comment: Yep.  I was missing the forest for the trees!

Comment: yup @ScottCWilson

Comment: Note for other SO users: the table is fully created by the `Rect` call - there's no need to close it; it's not like HTML.  You just position your pen after the table and start writing again.